# I bought 2 proxies which have almost identical IP address. Are they in the same network?

Tags: networking, ip

The IPs look like this:

```
XX.XX.XXX.207
XX.XX.XXX.186
```

where the Xs in the 2 IPs are identical. Are they in the same network? If I were to use a software which doesn't allow a user to have more than 1 account per IP, will they be suspicious of those 2 accounts from the same network using the software at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they're most likely are in the same network.

If the software company finds the address suspicious, its admins will likely start by checking 1) who is listed as the address owner in WHOIS, and 2) what is announcing this address via BGP. Both are public information and you can do these checks yourself, e.g. at https://bgp.he.net for a start.

However, most of the Internet does not accept advertisements prefixes longer than /24 via BGP, so it's practically guaranteed (even without checking) that `x.y.z.207` and `x.y.z.186` will fall under the same advertisement by the same network operator.

---

That said, "in the same network" doesn't mean much. Your neighbours using the same ISP as you are also in the same network; sometimes their IP addresses will even be within the same /24. Frequently, most customers of that ISP within the general area – and in some cases, even across the whole country – will fall under the same BGP route.

(Note that the software company's admins cannot tell, and generally don't really care, about whether the addresses are within the same *subnet*. Such information would be even more useless, as a subnet can be anything from a room to a country.)

---

So "same network" isn't what makes an address suspicious. That the address shows up as "owned by a company providing proxy services" is what you should be worried about.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the network configuration. You'd need the subnet mask to tell. What you do know is that they most likely belong to the same commercial entity. So if a service is banning a whole hoster both would probably be affected.